# SQL Transform/Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot, transform

I'm fairly new to this, and have done a lot of searching, but I'm not even 100% sure what exactly to search for, except I know I need to use Transform.

I basically need this:

```
Column A   Column B
 Total        184
 Half         20
 Some         25
 None         30
 Total        52
 Half         25
 Some         16
 None         86
```

To become:

```
Total   Half    Some    None
184      20      25      30
 52      25      16      86
```

Any help would be amazing, it's the last part of a query, then it's done.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any column that will associate the `Total=184`, `Half=20`, etc are supposed to be in the same row?  Data in a table is not inherently ordered. Does the order matter?

Comment: Ended up doing it in Access, it was very straightforward. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: @Crogacht You should post your final solution as an answer, then you can accept it which shows it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being something like this. Don't do it with the Query Wizard, it won't work out very well. This is Access 2010.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table.ColumnB) AS FirstOfColumnB
SELECT Table.Columns
FROM Table
GROUP BY Table.Columns
PIVOT Table.ColumnA;
```